# How to enter transaction callback in typeorm?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs, typeorm

I'm kind of new in unit testing and trying to make some test with typeorm.

The code I've is this:

```
    public executeTransaction(querys: IQueryTransaction[]) {
        return getManager().transaction(async transactionalManager => {
            for (const query of querys) {
                await transactionalManager.query(query[0], query[1]);
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to enter the `transaction` callBack but can't figured out how to do it. I tried to mock `getManager` and `transaction` playing with it, but with no results.

I'm using jest, typeorm and nest.

Someone knows how to do this?.

EDIT: Connecting to the database is not an option

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this...

```
return await getManager().transaction(async transactionalManager => {
  for (const query of querys) {
    await transactionalManager.query(query[0], query[1]);
  }
});
```

OR

```
import {getManager} from "typeorm";

await getManager().transaction(async transactionalManager => {
    await transactionalManager.save(users);
    await transactionalManager.save(photos);
});
```

OR

```
@Controller("/user")
export class UserController {
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
    ) {}

    @Post("/")
    @Transaction()
    async createNewUser(@Body() body: UserDTO) {        
        return await this.userService.createNewUser(body);
    }
}
```

Comment: An await is enough to mock it?. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: First tell me what you exactly want to do?

Comment: As my question said, I'm trying to unit test that section of code, but don't know how to do it

Comment: Basically we are using it as i mension in my above code with the OR section.

Comment: How do you mock the `transaction` callback?

Comment: @AlejandroBarone see my third part of the code in which i have explained it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Istambul to simplify your life.

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
```

Comment: As it stands this answer is unhelpful. Please extend your comment to clarify how it answers the question.